# Parent and Child products in same Object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am in a situation where I need products and its accessories in the same object. I got the products with following code:

```
@products = Product.all
```

This is fine. For getting accessories of each product in the same object, I did following:

```
@products.each do |product|
   @product.accessories = Product.find_by_parent_id(product.id)
end
```

I tried this but when I call @products, I have only products, no accessories.

In the model, I have called

```
attr_accessor :accessories
def accessories=(test)
   accessories = test
end
```

I am not getting any error but unfortunately I am not getting accessories as well. Is this the right way to get accessories? or is there any other way to achieve this? If I am doing it right way, then what mistake am I doing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you in Rails 4? Tell me if this is what you're trying to do: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to rely more on the database because Rails is just made for that and provides so many methods out of the box for it, methods that you can avoid reinventing.

Since each one of your products references other products, it's like a self join. Its accessories are just other products.

So first you need to add a `product_id` to the product model table (with a migration). This `product_id` will be used to reference "parents".

Then try putting something like this in your Product model:

```
has_many :accessories, class_name: "Product", foreign_key: :product_id
belongs_to :parent_product, class_name: "Product", foreign_key: :product_id
```

So then when you have a product in your hand, if it's an accessory, you just go `@product.parent_product` to get the parent, and if you have a "parent" in your hand, you just go `@product.accessories` and it will return an array of them.

Since you might be loading accessories pretty often from the parent product, add an `includes` statement to it to eager load the accessories automatically.

Learn more about the "out of the box" methods [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference). These include easy and straight forward ways of adding and removing "accessories" from a "parent", etc. (like `@product.acceesories = [array of accessories]`)

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking it of a different way. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you define `attr_accessor` in a Ruby class you don't need to override set method for an attribute unless you have a specific behavior. So `attr_accessor :accessories` would be enough, it will create both: get and set method.

But your mistake, I guess, is that you have to write data to `@accessories` variable instead of `accessories` as the attributes' values are stored in a instance variable which starts with `@`